# How to download .mp3 files whole site?

Tags: wget, httrack

I want to download all mp3 files in the website (even in home page and sublinks).

For example I want to download all .mp3 links from the "http://example.org/musics/" and all sub-links.

How can I do this by using `wget` or `httrack` commands?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

With wget command you can use:

```
wget -c -A '*.mp3' -r -l 1 -nd http://example.org/musics/
```

- `-c`: continue getting a partially-downloaded file.
- `-A`: only accept mp3 files. change this format with another format you want to download.
- `-r`: recurse
- `-l 1`: one level deep (ie, only files directly linked from this page)
- `-nd`: don't create a directory structure, just download all the files into current directory.

Answer (score 2):

If the files are not on the same server e.g. cdn or subdomain you need to add the parameter `-H` for Host spanning.

By default (For good reason) Wget’s recursive retrieval ignores hosts different than the one specified in your command. However, depending on the where the files are stored you might need to visit different hosts (or a different server name of the same host).