# Downloading linked images of a web

Tags: downloads, wget

Is it possible to download all .jpg and .png files linked in a web? I want to download the images from each post of each thread of [this forum][1] containing a link. For example [this post][2] contains a link to [this file][3].

I've tried with wget:

```
  wget -r -np http://www.mtgsalvation.com/forums/creativity/artwork/340782-official-digital-rendering-thread?
```

and it copied all the html files of that thread. Although I don't know why it jumps from `...thread?comment=336` to `...thread?comment=3232`, when it was going one by one until comment 336.

Comment: Did you try suggested answer? I tested it on my site, it goes through html page tree and gets all linked images.

Comment: Yes I tried it without the -A jpg,png option and it only downloads an index.html. When I do it with that option it doesn't downloads anything.

Comment: Could you post exactly the url you are trying to get? I will test it this evening and I'll give you a feedback.

Comment: I don't understand very well what url you are refering. I'll try to explain the question better.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to download .mp3 files whole site?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/549360/how-to-download-mp3-files-whole-site)

Comment: The .mp3 files in that question are located in the same page that you have to use the wget in.

Comment: You are right, `wget` against this site doesn't work as expected. So, I updated my answer, could you try and let's see if it work as you want? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> // for using system calls
#include <unistd.h> // for sleep

int main ()
{
    char  body[] = "forum-post-body-content", notes[] = "p-comment-notes", img[] = "img src=", link[200], cmd[200]={0}, file[10];
    int c, pos = 0, pos2 = 0, fin = 0, i, j, num = 0, found = 0;
    FILE *fp;

    for (i = 1; i <= 149; ++i)
    {
        sprintf(cmd,"wget -O page%d.txt 'http://www.mtgsalvation.com/forums/creativity/artwork/340782-official-digital-rendering-thread?page=%d'",i,i);
        system(cmd);
        sprintf(file, "page%d.txt", i);
        fp = fopen (file, "r");
        while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
        {
            if (body[pos] == c)
            {
                if (pos == 22)
                {
                    pos = 0;
                    while (fin == 0)
                    {
                        c = fgetc (fp);
                        if (feof (fp))
                            break;
                        if (notes[pos] == c)
                        {
                            if (pos == 14)
                            {
                                fin = 1;
                                pos = -1;
                            }
                            ++pos;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if(pos > 0)
                                pos = 0;
                        }
                        if (img[pos2] == c)
                        {
                            if (pos2 == 7)
                            {
                                pos2 = 0;
                                while (found == 0)
                                {
                                    c = fgetc (fp); // get char from file
                                    link[pos2] = c;
                                    if (pos2 > 0)
                                    {
                                        if(link[pos2-1] == 'g' && link[pos2] == '\"')
                                        {
                                        found = 1;
                                        }
                                    }
                                    ++pos2;
                                }
                                --pos2;
                                found = 0;
                                char link2[pos2];
                                for (j = 1; j < pos2; ++j)
                                {
                                    link2[j - 1] = link[j];
                                }
                                link2[j - 1] = '\0';
                                sprintf(cmd, "wget -O /home/arturo/Dropbox/Digital_Renders/%d \'%s\'", ++num, link2);
                                system(cmd);
                                pos2 = -1;
                            }
                            ++pos2;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if(pos2 > 0)
                                pos2 = 0;
                        }
                    }
                fin = 0;
                }
                ++pos;
            }
            else
                pos = 0;
        }
        // closing file
        fclose (fp);
        if (remove (file))
            fprintf(stderr, "Can't remove file\n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try with this command:

```
wget -P path/where/save/result -A jpg,png -r http://www.mtgsalvation.com/forums/creativity/artwork/
```

According to [wget man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/wget.1.html):

```
    -A acclist --accept acclist
        Specify comma-separated lists of file name suffixes or patterns to
        accept or reject (@pxref{Types of Files} for more details).
    -P prefix
        Set directory prefix to prefix.  The directory prefix is the direc‐
        tory where all other files and subdirectories will be saved to,
        i.e. the top of the retrieval tree.  The default is . (the current
        directory).
    -r
    --recursive
        Turn on recursive retrieving.
```

---

Try this:

```
    mkdir wgetDir
    wget -P wgetDir http://www.mtgsalvation.com/forums/creativity/artwork/340782-official-digital-rendering-thread?page=145
```

This command will get html page and put it in `wgetDir`. When I tried this command I found this file:

```
    340782-official-digital-rendering-thread?page=145
```

then, I tried this command:

```
    wget -P wgetDir -A png,jpg,jpeg,gif -nd --force-html -r -i "wgetDir/340782-official-digital-rendering-thread?page=145"
```

and it downloads images. So, it seems to work, although I do not know if these pictures are the ones you want to download.